# Facebook like not supporting IE7. work around?

Tags: jquery, facebook-like

As you're always so good at answering my questions, here's another one for you! Basically Facebook have stopped supporting IE7 as of last week and so when their 'like' button is loaded up on our site in IE7 it throws up an unresponsive script error that asks the user if they want to continue running the script.

What I want to do is find the version of the web browser being used and if it's IE7 or older, not load the facebook like script.

This is the script I've come up with, cobbled together from a couple of places;

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
//check for IE7
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.")!=-1) {
    $("#facebookPluginContainer").hide();
} else {
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&status=0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}

});
```

It seems to work as it should in all browsers, but IE10 doesn't seem to show the facebook like button, is there something in my code that isn't supported by IE10?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to turn compatibility mode off in IE10?

Also see: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/669917143021665